# How can error stack traces be logged in Azure Durable Functions for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, source-maps, azure-durable-functions

We are using Azure Durable Functions with Typescript and the framework and runtime works great as such, but when a trigger or orchestration fails and throws an exception we are left scratching our head as to where the error actually happened.

In Application Insights, I can see the failing function and the error message but no stack trace. At best, I get a dotNet stacktrace from the framework running the function but nothing from where the actual method failed.

When googling around, I haven't been able to find any sources on how to configure this if it is at all possible. At best, I've found recommendations of using `inlineSourceMap` in the Typescript compilation settings but this isn't automatically used from what I can see.

The best I've managed now is to wrap the various handlers (http, timer, servicebus) with try-catches and log at least the stacktrace of the error, even if it will be in javascript references as opposed to Typescript.

[image: Screenshot from Application Insights]

Comment: You need to use `context: InvocationContext` to log the errors in Call Stack

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I a using context.df.log and context.df.error. Using context.df.trace I have now been able to get the stacktrace out but it is still outputting it only with javascript references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a default typescript Durable function in vs code which is having below code in it.

**durableHello1.ts**-

```js
import { app, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, InvocationContext } from '@azure/functions';
import * as df from 'durable-functions';
import { ActivityHandler, OrchestrationContext, OrchestrationHandler } from 'durable-functions';

const activityName = 'durableHello1';

const durableHello1Orchestrator: OrchestrationHandler = function* (context: OrchestrationContext) {
    const outputs = [];
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Tokyo'));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Seattle'));
    outputs.push(yield context.df.callActivity(activityName, 'Cairo'));

    return outputs;
};
df.app.orchestration('durableHello1Orchestrator', durableHello1Orchestrator);

const durableHello1: ActivityHandler = (input: string): string => {
    return `Hello, ${input}`;
};
df.app.activity(activityName, { handler: durableHello1 });

const durableHello1HttpStart: HttpHandler = async (request: HttpRequest, context: InvocationContext): Promise<HttpResponse> => {
    const client = df.getClient(context);
    const body: unknown = await request.text();
    const instanceId: string = await client.startNew(request.params.orchestratorName, { input: body });

    context.log(`Started orchestration with ID = '${instanceId}'.`);

    return client.createCheckStatusResponse(request, instanceId);
};

app.http('durableHello1HttpStart', {
    route: 'orchestrators/{orchestratorName}',
    extraInputs: [df.input.durableClient()],
    handler: durableHello1HttpStart,
});
```

**host.json**-

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Then I deployed the function to the function app and invoked the function using an incorrect orchestrator function name. I am able to see the error in stack trace in application insight.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the elaborate answer! perhaps I am simply looking in the wrong place. Are you accessing this from Application Insights -> Failures or somewhere else?

Comment: I am looking this in Application Insight --> transaction search

Comment: Excellent. I think that's the actual answer, bundled with that perhaps you have to throw the error as an exception in order to get the callstack. When I'm just doing a log or a trace, I can't seem to see the call stacks